# XSLT Split into files based on Child Element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an XML of the following style

```
<Animals>
   <Dog>
     <Name>Clifford</Name>
     <LikesFetch>Yes</LikesFetch>
      ...
     <Colour>Red</Colour>
   </Dog>
   ...
   <Cat>
      <Name>Garfield</Name>
      <Food>Fish</Fish>
       ...
      <Colour>Orange</Colour>
   <Cat>
   ...
   <Bird>
      ...
   </Bird>
</Animals>
```

And I want to use xsl:result-document href="{name}.xml" from XSLT 2.0 to split this up into files for each colour, with all the animals associated with that colour.
E.g.
Red.XML

```
<Animals>
   <Dog>
      <Name>Clifford</Name>
      ...
      <Colour>Red</Colour>
   <Dog>
   <Cat>
      <Name>Ruby</Name>
      ...
      <Colour>Red</Colour>
   </Cat>
   ...
</Animals>
```

There are only a small number of types of animal (say, bird, cat, and dog). However there are lots of different colours, so they cannot be hardcoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard solution:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Animals/*" group-by=".//Colour">
  <xsl:result-document href="{current-grouping-key()}">
    <animals colour="{current-grouping-key()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
    </animals>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```